# GCP Cloud Function Axios external request Timeout

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, axios, google-cloud-functions

So I'm trying to make a request to an external API using Axios inside a GCP Cloud Function.

The problem is, when I run it with functions-framework locally, it runs smoothly.

When it's deployed, I always get a timeout when the axios call is running.

This is what's inside the cloud function:

```
const Jiva = new JivaAuth(jivaUser, jivaPass);
    
await Jiva.doLogin();
```

And this is doLogin method:

```
 async doLogin() {
    
    const serviceName = 'MobileLoginSP.login';
    const serviceRequest = `<serviceRequest serviceName='${serviceName}'>
            <requestBody>
                <NOMUSU>${this.#user}</NOMUSU>
                <INTERNO2>${this.#pass}</INTERNO2>
            </requestBody>
        </serviceRequest>`;
    const loginUrl = `${this.#serviceLocation}${serviceName}${this.#counterLogin}`;
    const response = await axiosInstance.post(loginUrl, serviceRequest);
    
    let mappedResponse;
    parseString(response.data, (err, mappedResult) => (mappedResponse = mappedResult));
    const statusLogin = mappedResponse?.serviceResponse?.$?.status;

    // Handling wrong status code
    if (statusLogin !== '1') {
      // Checking error message, if any
      const errMessage = mappedResponse?.serviceResponse?.statusMessage;
      if (errMessage && Array.isArray(errMessage)) throw new Error(errMessage[0]);
      throw new Error(`ERR001`);
    }

    this.#mgeSession = mappedResponse?.serviceResponse?.responseBody[0].jsessionid[0];
    axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['Cookie'] = `JSESSIONID=${this.#mgeSession}`;
  }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Which type is your Cloud Function? Schedule? Background (i.e. triggered with a Firestore doc creation)? What do you see if you debug the code? Is the first call returning a response?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the third party service I was trying to access does not allow request outside my region, which is the case with GCP. Nothing wrong about the code.

Comment: How you added outside request allow in GCP ?
I am using VPC and I added firebase rule to allow all outgoing request in all ports, and still getting same issue. @Rodolfo